# Changing the value of a field from a table when another is changed using triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, triggers, sql-update

Good morning everyone.
I have a table like this in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE NC
(
        ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT null,
        reportingDate DATE,
        closingDate DATE,
        State VARCHAR(20),
        PRIMARY KEY(CodNC)
)
```

What I need is to automatically changing the value of the field "ClosingDate" up to today everytime the value of the field "State" is changed with "Closed" using TRIGGERS.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple `before update` trigger:

```
delimiter //

create trigger trg_nc_before_state_update
before update on nc
for each row
begin
    if new.state = 'Closed' and not old.state <=> 'Closed' then
        set new.closingdate = current_date;
    end if;
end
//

delimiter ;
```